# Excel/VBA - How to make same edits to every existing cell in column

Tags: excel, vba

How do I add ="=" to every cell with values in a column? (example shown in pic). I read that this method will allow me to get exact matches when applying an advanced filter. I tried doing the AutoFill method (double clicking the square on bottom of highlighted cell) but it just replaces every cell in the column with the value in the first row.
[image]

Comment: what about `="""" & B1 & """"` and dragging down?

Comment: I tried your method but is there a way to remove the extra quotation marks that appears in the output?

Comment: those extra quotation marks are, according to your image, is what you are looking for. So the formula returns `"ABC"`

Comment: I'm looking for ="B1" so the output still looks like B1

Comment: If you are trying to overwrite all your values with a formula referencing the values you are overwriting you obviously cannot fill that down. You will need to loop over all those cells in your column. Plenty of examples on how to loop cells =). GL

Comment: What's the problem with the advanced filter? This is sounding like an XY problem.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook The advanced filter doesn't return an exact match when the selection criteria used is a range (e.g. 89870991041415***000*** will return not just that number, but also 89870991041415**001**, 89870991041415**002**, and so on. I read that adding ="=(number here)"  to the numbers apparently solves the issue

Comment: Use " in advanced filter, not on your values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

[image]

```
="="""&A1&""""
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but think of it as applying a formula to the cell. The formula would be =" ".  Excel apparently needs this formatting if i want to have exact matches when applying an advanced filter

Comment: *think of it as applying a formula to the cell.* Well, this **is** a formula. Maybe you mean values? Have you tried with ths formula, drag, and then copy/paste as values ?

Comment: Apologies if i can't explain well but i made some edits to the question that will hopefully make things clearer. The dragging method doesn't work for me

Comment: You need to drag on a helper column, not in the original one. Then you can copy and paste as values, and delete the first column if needed.